# Install packages in xamarin.shared with NuGet

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

I think that installing packages in **xamarin native shared** with NuGet is impossible but I was wondering how exactly should I include libraries from nuget and xamarin in my shared project exactly?

I can't find anything on this and I can't use any 'basic' package, from OAuth2 to Http requests. Any idea on how to do this?

If the library is C# shouldn't it be able to run on all platforms? Why exactly can't I nuget Oauth2 or Http requests?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to add nuget package?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using shared projects, you have to add the packages to the projects, where your shared project is included (e.g. your Android or iOS App). Shared projects do **not** create **a library**. They are just some sort of **file linking**. If you use shared projects, the files from this projects behave like they were directly included in the project that is using your shared project.

For a comparison of the possibilities have a look at: https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Comment: Hello sven, thank you for your help. Would you just be more specific regarding my case? How exactly should I add the package? I have three folders in my project: x, x.Droid, x.iOS. If I right click in x, "manage nuget packages" is greyed out. If I right click in x.Droid or x.iOS and seelct "manage nuget packages" I get the error `x.Droid (or iOS) nuget configuration is invalid`... What steps should I follow to use xamarin auth in my app?

Comment: If `nuget configuration is invalid` this means something is wrong with your installation or nuget manager. Can you try to update the nuget manager via `Tools > Extensions > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery` and restart VS and try it again?